# Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'template'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the HTML tag  to build a table and got the error in the title.

Here is the template:

```
<template ngfor let-log [ngForOf]="logs">
  <tr>
    <td [lgStatus]="log.level" class="ion-record"></td>
    <td>{{log.timestamp | date:'medium'}}</td>
    <td>{{log.source}}</td>
    <td>{{log.message}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colSpan="4">{{log.detailedMessage}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

I checked several threads and I correctly imported the BrowserModule in the app.module.ts and the CommonModule in the component related to this template.

I don't see what I have done wrong here :(

Thanks in advance for your help.
Serge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact syntax will be `ngFor` not `ngfor` so use your code like this-

```
<template ngFor let-log [ngForOf]="logs">
```

for more type you can refer here

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<template ngfor let-log [ngForOf]="logs">
```

has to be

```
<template ngFor let-log [ngForOf]="logs">
            ^
```

You can use `<ng-container>` instead of `<template>` to be able to use the more common syntax

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let log of logs">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo,

```
<template ngFor let-log [ngForOf]="logs">
```